# What are these raid errors?

Tags: raid, software-raid, centos7

I installed a new server with two sets of mirrored RAID 1 drives. The system sees 2 1TB drives, each of which is a mirrored set. This is a software raid (no hardware controller) done at BIOS level. I am running Centos 7.

Everything seems to work fine. But my logwatch contains this every night:

--------------------- Mdadm Begin ------------------------

```
mdadm: cannot open metadata=ddf: No such file or directory
metadata=ddf :
mdadm: cannot open container=61190dff:3e61006d:a919273a:2d41fa1e: No such file or directory
container=61190dff:3e61006d:a919273a:2d41fa1e :
mdadm: cannot open container=61190dff:3e61006d:a919273a:2d41fa1e: No such file or directory
container=61190dff:3e61006d:a919273a:2d41fa1e :
```

---------------------- Mdadm End -------------------------

Should I be concerned? Is there a way to fix this? It appears as though linux is trying to manage the RAID even though it is at a BIOS level?

Comment: You are using software RAID (even though your seems to use the BIOS to help set it up. See "fake RAID"). This means then you do need drivers/software to manage it. In your case that is mdadm.

Comment: So how do I fix these errors?